# When building Yate from sources on Centos 6.10, the error appears on the configure phase

Tags: autoconf, yate

The build plan is:

```
./autogen.sh 
./configure
make
sudo make install-noapi
```

To make `./autogen.sh` working I have installed

```
yum install autoconf
```

On `./configure` phase I got this error:

```
sudo ./configure
checking for local operating system type... Linux
checking for libraries directory name... lib64
checking for g++... no
checking for c++... no
checking for gpp... no
checking for aCC... no
checking for CC... no
checking for cxx... no
checking for cc++... no
checking for cl.exe... no
checking for FCC... no
checking for KCC... no
checking for RCC... no
checking for xlC_r... no
checking for xlC... no
checking for C++ compiler default output file name...
configure: error: in `/root/yate':
configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system was missing devtools, I had to install them to fix:

```
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools" -y
```